# How to enable the use of HTTP_RANGE on server

Tags: php, http

If I run the following script to test for HTTP_RANGE on my server I get a 'no' response. Is there something in my LAMP server that I need to set for this to give me a yes? I can't seem to find any info regarding this, only how to test for it's existence.

```
<?php
if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_RANGE'])) {
    echo "yes";
} elseif (isset($_ENV['HTTP_RANGE'])) {
    echo "yes";
} else {
    echo "no";
}
```

Comment: What client are you using? Is the client including an `Accept-Ranges` header in its request?

Comment: I am using Firefox to view an mp4 file through JWPlayer. When I examine the headers using the firefox addon 'Live HTTP Headers' it shows this :
`code` Server: Apache
X-Mod-H264-Streaming: version=2.2.7
Content-Length: 383183
Last-Modified: Sun, 15 Apr 2012 23:04:52 GMT
Etag: "5dc6b-4bdbfbbae2d00;383183"
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Cache-Control: max-age=31536000, public, must-revalidate, proxy-revalidate
Expires: Wed, 17 Apr 2013 04:13:11 GMT
Pragma: public
Keep-Alive: timeout=15, max=100
Connection: Keep-Alive
Content-Type: video/mp4

Comment: Those are the response headers, not the request headers (which might contain a `Range: bytes=100000-` entry).

Comment: is this the request? `code` http://www.mysite.com/forums/files/preview/2_715bb3d31274ae0390e322d5e080dca6.mp4

GET /forums/files/preview/2_715bb3d31274ae0390e322d5e080dca6.mp4 HTTP/1.1
Host: www.mysite.com
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:11.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/11.0
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Language: en-us,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Connection: keep-alive
Cookie: wp-settings-1=...

Comment: what I am trying to accomplish is being able to view an mp4 file like this through JWPlayer, but using php to deliver it using fread or something similar, and also viewing with an Android mobile phone. So far I can get the php to deliver the file through JWPlayer successfully when viewed on my desktop pc but it always fails on the mobile. If I just hand JWPlayer a direct url link to the file it will play on the mobile. So I know that the mp4 is compatible, just not how to deliver it to the mobile phone using php. Maybe HTTP_RANGE is not what I need to ask about and should start a new question.

Answer (score 1):

This variable is only present if the client ('user agent') makes a request asking for certain range of bytes (a Accept-Ranges request header) instead of the whole document. These are not defined for regular requests. Are you sure that your user agent asks for byte range?

Comment: I am getting this in my headers `code` Accept-Ranges: bytes  when viewing an mp4 through JWPlayer using a direct url to the file.